# Getting selected index from jQuery Mobile Selectmenu Widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a problem getting the selected index of the select widget. Here is the HTML

```
<div data-role="content" id="resultados">
    <label for="select-choice-0" class="select">Resultados:</label> 
    <select name="select-choice-0" id="listaResultados"></select>   
</div>
```

I dynamically add options to the widget this way (this works):

```
$listaRe = $("#listaResultados");
$listaRe.html("");
for(i=0;i<results.length;i++){
    $listaRe.append("<option value='"+i+"'>"+results[i]+"</option>");
}       
// results is a predefined array
```

When I try to obtain the selected index every time is changed it always print "Index: 0":

```
$listaRe.change(function(){
console.log("Index: "+$listaRe.selectedIndex);
});
```

I'm using jQuery 1.8.1 and jQuery Moble 1.2.0

Thanks!

Comment: it seems results is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple issue:-

- `$listaRe` here is a jQuery object
- and jQuery objects have no property like `selectedIndex`

So, either you can do this:

```
$listaRe.on('change', function () {
    console.log("Index: " + $listaRe[0].selectedIndex);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/etKtw/)

or this:-

```
$listaRe.on('change', function () {
    console.log("Index: " + $listaRe.prop("selectedIndex"));
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/etKtw/1/)

to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.on` method. Here is the working code:

```
$('#resultados').on('change','#listaResultados',function(){
alert($('option:selected',$(this)).index());
});
```

Check the working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/rhyC5/

Answer (score 0):

Considering results length is 5:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $listaRe = $("#listaResultados");
             $listaRe.html("");
                for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    $listaRe.append("<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>");
                }
                // results is a predefined array
              $listaRe.change(function () {
              console.log("Index: " + $listaRe.prop("selectedIndex"));
        });
 })
```

Comment: I believe console.log("Index: " + $listaRe.prop("selectedIndex")); would work too?